# I would like to ungroup items but this option is no longer working for me. What Can I do?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Starting with a new image in Illustrator, the ungroup option is greyed out and the expand option. When I select only the whole object is chosen. What settings do I need to change. Been on many hours with trial and error and havent found the answer in you tube or google

Comment: We will need some more info to help here. What is the "New Image" you are starting with ? Is it an actual Raster Image ? When the "whole object" is selected what does it say in the upper left corner of the Control Bar ? Perhaps it is a Compound Path that you will need to release ? Perhaps you could post a screenshot ? Otherwise I do not think there is any way for us to help.

Comment: Open the Layers panel and the Appearance panel. Select the problematic object and check the panels. Item in the layers panel can have subitems . Show what there is including all subitems. BTW. If your object happens to be a linked item or a single bitmap image the behaviour is normal.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, impossible to answer as presented. There are a number of reasons something can't be "ungrouped". Without seeing the artwork and the expanded layers panel, all anyone can do is *guess*.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting CTRL+SHIFT+G with the object selected, but if the Ungroup option is grayed out, there is probably a single object, and not a group.

Try hitting CTRL+Y and see you if can spot multiple objects in outline view.